# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false'

Tags: laravel, react-native, expo

I'm trying to make a JWT auth with laravel on my back and react-native (with expo) on my front. I have already set up my endpoint to get my token and is working properly.

It says that a file is not accessible but I don't understand what is that file for and why it has an IP inside the route.

I'm getting this issue:

[ENOENT ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpqcH.png)
My code is:

```
imports...

const baseUrl = 'http://192.168.1.163:8000';

const SignInScreen = ({ navigation }) => {

    const [data, setData] = React.useState({
        username: '',
        password: '',
        check_textInputChange: false,
        secureTextEntry: true,
        isValidUser: true,
        isValidPassword: true,
    });

    const { signIn } = React.useContext(AuthContext);

    const textInputChange = (val) => {
        if (val.trim().length >= 4) {
            setData({
                ...data,
                username: val,
                check_textInputChange: true,
                isValidUser: true
            });
        } else {
            setData({
                ...data,
                username: val,
                check_textInputChange: false,
                isValidUser: false
            });
        }
    }

    const handlePasswordChange = (val) => {
        if (val.trim().length >= 8) {
            setData({
                ...data,
                password: val,
                isValidPassword: true
            });
        } else {
            setData({
                ...data,
                password: val,
                isValidPassword: false
            });
        }
    };

    const updateSecureTextEntry = () => {
        setData({
            ...data,
            secureTextEntry: !data.secureTextEntry
        })
    };

    const loginHandle = async (username, password) => {
        var token;
        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                grant_type: "password",
                client_id: "1",
                client_secret: "blabla",
                username: username,
                password: password,
                scope: "*"
            })
        };

        fetch(`${baseUrl}/oauth/token/`, requestOptions)
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
                response.json().then((data) => {
                    token = data.access_token;
                });
            });

        if (token == 'undefined') {
            Alert.alert('Invalid user', 'El usuario no existe, o la contraseña o usuario son incorrectas ¿Estás seguro de que tienes cuenta?',
                [
                    { text: 'Okey' }
                ]);
        }
        else {
            signIn(username, password, token);
        }
        signIn(username, password);
    }

    return (
       Some html code that runs loginhandle
    );
};

export default SignInScreen;
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason why you are getting this error is because you are logging the raw response:

`console.log(response)`

You need to first use the `json()` and afterwards you can `console.log` that result.

Took me a while to figure that out!